# Return and Save XML Object From Sharepoint List Web Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, web-services

I am trying to populate a variable with an XML response from an ajax call on page load so that on keyup I can filter through that list without making repeated get requests (think very rudimentary autocomplete). The trouble that I am having seems to be potentially related to variable scoping but I am fairly new to js/jQuery so I am not quite certain.

The following code doesn't do anything on key up and adding alerts to it tells me that it is executing `leadResults()` on keyup and that the variable is returning an XML response object but it appears to be empty. The strange bit is that if I move the `leadResults()` call into the `getResults()` function the UL is populated with the results correctly.

Im beating my head against the wall on this one, please help!

```
var resultsXml;

$(document).ready( function() {
    var leadLookupCaml =
         "<Query> \
            <Where> \
                <Eq> \
                  <FieldRef Name=\"Lead_x0020_Status\"/> \
                  <Value Type=\"Text\">Active</Value> \
                </Eq> \
            </Where> \
         </Query>"

    $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetListItems",
                    webURL: "http://sharepoint/departments/sales",
                    listName: "Leads",
                    CAMLQuery: leadLookupCaml,
                    CAMLRowLimit: 0,                    
                    completefunc: getResults    
                });

})

$("#lead_search").keyup( function(e) {

leadResults();

})



function getResults(xData, status) {
resultsXml = xData;

}   

function leadResults() {
xData = resultsXml;
   $("#lead_results li").remove();
   $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {

        var selectHtml = 
            "<li>"
             + "<a href=\"http://sharepoint/departments/sales/Lists/Lead%20Groups/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + ">" + $(this).attr("ows_Title")+" : " + $(this).attr("ows_Phone")    + "</a>\
             </li>";
        $("#lead_results").append(selectHtml);



    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After proof reading my submission it was blindingly obvious! The ajax call needed to be made synchronously. Setting async to false saved the day!